# How to display in the frontend the total amount of products sold ever woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, orders

can anyone help me to display the total amount of units sold ever in the woocommerce store? I want to show it in the main page as one of our statistics. Please help.

I've alreay tried this code added, but the result is this one:

Produto                                 Units Sold
Calculadora de impresión 3D online  1051
Calculadora de impressão 3D online  1046

And I need to know the total of its, and later be able to multiply the total *8, for example, to show the kg of material material consumed to produce each product.

```html
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'meta_key' => 'total_sales',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'total_sales',
            'value' => 0,
            'compare' => '>'
        )
    )
);

$output = array_reduce( get_posts( $args ), function( $result, $post ) {
    return $result .= '<tr><td>' . $post->post_title . '</td><td>' . get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'total_sales', true ) . '</td></tr>';
} );

echo '<table><thead><tr><th>' . __( 'Product', 'woocommerce' ) . '</th><th>' . __( 'Units Sold', 'woocommerce' ) . '</th></tr></thead>' . $output . '</table>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code at theme's functions.php file to show total product sold in the single product page

add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'total_product_sold_count', 10 );

```
function total_product_sold_count() {
global $product;
$units_sold = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), 'total_sales', true );
if ( $units_sold ) echo '<p>' . sprintf( __( 'Total Sold: %s', 'woocommerce' ), $units_sold ) . '</p>';
}
```